Is it possible to change the colour / color of a C# class based on the type in Visual Studio / Rider / R#
We have .NET 8 C# classes that inherit from Event and Command.
It would be nice to see the Something : Event class in a different color within the IDE.
Is there a R# plugin that can color classes based on their type / rules?

Not in Visual Studio. You can choose different colors for classes, structs, delegates,  enums, etc., but not for different classes. See: Change fonts, colors, and themes in Visual Studio

What about a custom plugin. Does one exist. I don't really want to write one.

I did not find a way to colorize different types in code; however, you can colorize the document tabs by specifying a Regular Expression. To do this,

Click on the settings icon (cogwheel) to the right of the document tabs.
Under [Color Document Tabs by] select [Regular Expression].
Then click [Configure Regular Expressions] to open the configuration file. It contains a explanatory text.
Add Regular Expressions for each desired document group
As the text mentioned above says: "You can customize the color assigned to any group of files by right-clicking the tab and choosing "Set Tab Color."


